# System.TypeLoadException while using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, typeloadexception

I'm attempting to use Dapper on Northwind database, and i have a problem that i'm unable to fix.
I get this error:
`System.TypeLoadException: 'Cannot load type 'Dapper.SqlMapper' from set 'Dapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'`

My code:

```cs
class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TerritoryDescription { get; set; }
        public string RegionDescription { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName} {Title} {TerritoryDescription} {RegionDescription}";
        }
    }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connStr = "Server = localhost; Database = Northwind; Trusted_Connection = True;";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var employees = connection.Query<Employee> 
                (
                    @"SELECT e.FirstName FirstName, e.LastName LastName, e.Title Title, T.TerritoryDescription TerritoryDesc, r.RegionDescription RegionDesc FROM Employees e INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON e.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID INNER JOIN Territories T ON et.TerritoryID = T.TerritoryID JOIN Region r ON T.RegionID = r.RegionID"
                ).ToList();

                foreach (var person in employees) Console.WriteLine(person);

                connection.Close();
            }              
        }
    }
```

I can't even check where is the problem, because app goes into break mode.

Comment: Dont declare anything with name as dapper or Dapper in your project

Comment: So what should i change? I can't see anything here named Dapper.

Comment: It's not there even in any namespace which you have defined?

Comment: Namespace is called `DapperCSV`, it shouldn't be a problem i believe.

Comment: Is your project called "Dapper" by any chance? Or the default namespace?

Comment: Yes, change it and then try. If it doesn't work then install the dapper again after changing the name. It will work 100%

Comment: Pretty unusual behavior but hopefully it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs generally when there is an object / class / type named

Dapper

dapper

Do following steps to remove this issue

Create a Fresh Project and do NOT name anything in it with Dapper (case insensitive). Even if you change name of exiting 'dapper' object in your existing project then too it might create problems so its better to create a fresh project! I think it has something to do with assembly or hardcoding somewhere in dapper or visual studio (not sure!).

Use Nuget Manager again to Install Dapper.

It should work fine now.

**Reference** : https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/29410020/dapper-error--could-not-load-type--dapper-sqlmapper-